# AMO Database object does not refresh after restore

Tags: c#, database, ssas, olap-cube

```
amoServer.Restore(abfFile, db.Name, true);
amoServer.Databases.GetByName(db.Name).LastUpdate = db.LastUpdate;
```

I am copying one SSAS database from one server and to another.  Since the database is restoring, the last update get set... so I want to change it back.  However it appears that the collection of Databases never gets updated with the new database.  I've tried `.Refresh()` and `.Update()` before the call, but I still get an error

> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AmoException: The 'Database' with 'Name' =
>   'SomeReallyLongName' doesn't exist in the collection.

Anyone ever done this before?

Comment: What object did you try .Refresh() on? Can you include that in the code sample?

Comment: `.Refresh` is a method on `amoServer` not `amoServer.Databases`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
amoServer.Restore(abfFile, db.Name, true);
amoServer.Refresh(true, RefreshType.LoadedObjectsOnly);
Database dbRestore = amoServer.Databases.GetByName(db.Name);
dbRestore.LastUpdate = db.LastUpdate;
dbRestore.Update();
```

I'm not sure setting the LastUpdate will work as you hope but I suspect you have to do a .Update() to save that change.

Comment: I'm mirroring the databases and checking if one or the other has changed by looking at the LastUpdate.  When one side has a really old database that hasn't been mirrored, it restores it on the other side and the LastUpdate updated.  Then the app comes along and thinks there was a change made on the mirrored side and wants to restore it again...  If I can keep the LastUpdate in sync, it would be better than having a control table.

Comment: @DanAndrews edited my answer to deal with LastUpdate. I'm not optimistic but please try it.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow.  Thanks for keeping an eye on this.